# QmodelIndex and header data

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I have a 4 tableviews in my ui screen .In my header data function for 4 views , I just need one 1 row name- temperature for view 1 and 3 and four rows with name field 1x,field 4x, field 10x, field 40x respectively.
My function is

```
virtual QVariant headerData(int section,Qt::Orientation orientation,
                int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        switch(role)
        {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            switch (orientation)
            {
            case Qt::Vertical:
 switch (m_channel)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        switch (section)    // Range
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return "Temperature1";
                        }
                    case 1:
                        switch (section)    // Range
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return "Field 1x range";
                        case 1:
                            return "Field 4x range";
                        case 2:
                            return "Field 10x range";
                        case 3:
                            return "Field 40x range";
                        }
                    case 2:
                        switch (section)    // Range
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return "Temperature2";
                        }
                    case 3:
                        switch (section)    // Range
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return "Field 1x range";
                        case 1:
                            return "Field 4x range";
                        case 2:
                            return "Field 10x range";
                        case 3:
                            return "Field 40x range";
                        }
```

But, the screen when compiled shows temperature,field 4x, field 10x, field 40x for views 1 and view 3, which I don't wont

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing breaks in your `switch` statement.  For example:

```
                    switch (m_channel)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        switch (section)    // Range
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return "Temperature1";
                        }
                        break; // <-- You need this.
                    case 1:
                        ...
```

It's also generally a good idea to provide a `default` label for `switch` statements.

Comment: I tried used break statements ,instead when compiled I got temperature, 2 ,3,4 instead of just temperature in vertical header.